# Move cursor by percentage

Tags: cursor-movement

I know that you can go to the Nth % percentage of a file by typing N% in normal mode. Is it possible to advance the line by a given percentage?

To clarify, for an example, can I type something to advance to 10% of the file, then the same thing to advance to 20% and so on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
function! <SID>PercentUp()
    execute 'normal ' . max([line('.') * 100 / line('$') - v:count1 * 10, 0]) . '%'
endfunction

function! <SID>PercentDown()
    execute 'normal ' . min([line('.') * 100 / line('$') + v:count1 * 10, 100]) . '%'
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>- :<C-u>call <SID>PercentUp()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>+ :<C-u>call <SID>PercentDown()<CR>
```

With these <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> will recede by 10%, while <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> will advance by 10%.  The macros accept counters.

Comment: Nice (+1). - Have you an idea why the macros don't work if in line 1 of the data file?

Comment: @Janis Apparently the `<C-u>` didn't work the way I imagined it.  Without it the macros work from everywhere (well, hopefully), but they no longer take a count.  I'm not sure I understand why though.

Comment: @Janis I found a version that accepts counters, but it seems unnecessarily complicated. _shrug_